# Google Dropped Pin Link not showing in Website (Deskop) nor in Google Maps (iphone App)

Tags: iphone, google-maps

I have a Google-dropped-link.

On the iPhone (latest updates installed - 12.4.1) it opens first the website only with a button to open the app.

By clicking on it, it opens the app but does not show the location.

So I did type the link on my desktop browser (Firefox) and it does not show the link either.

If I click on the directions button the red-dot shows up.